# Determining directory name path

Tags: vb.net, filesystemwatcher

If I use this statement in a file watcher routine, how do I access what the directory path is that the change occurred in?

```
watcher = New FileSystemWatcher With {.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.DirectoryName Or NotifyFilters.FileName Or NotifyFilters.Attributes}
```

I used the full path member in the handler method, but it gives me the directory as well as the file name. So I just want to get the directory affected. How would I access that?

Comment: [System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getdirectoryname?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Path_GetDirectoryName_System_String_)

Comment: Thanks GSerg ::)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the

> Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath)

that GSerg suggested, and this was the statement that I needed to find the directory name that I was searching for. This solved my problem.